# create student database in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I'm a beginner in python. I have created a database for student in python. I'm not able to get the output for all iterations in dict.

my source code:-

```
n = int(raw_input("Please enter number of students:"))

student_data = ['stud_name', 'stud_rollno', 'mark1', 'mark2','mark3','total', 'average'] for i in range(0,n):

    stud_name=raw_input('Enter the name of student: ')
    print stud_name


    stud_rollno=input('Enter the roll number of student: ')
    print stud_rollno


    mark1=input('Enter the marks in subject 1: ')
    print mark1

    mark2=input('Enter the marks in subject 2: ')
    print mark2

    mark3=input('Enter the marks in subject 3: ')
    print mark3

    total=(mark1+mark2+mark3)
    print"Total is: ", total

    average=total/3
    print "Average is :", average

dict = {'Name': stud_name, 'Rollno':stud_rollno, 'Mark1':mark1, 'Mark2':mark2,'Mark3':mark3, 'Total':total, 'Average':average} print "dict['Name']: ", dict['Name'] print "dict['Rollno']: ", dict['Rollno'] print "dict['Mark1']: ", dict['Mark1'] print "dict['Mark2']: ", dict['Mark2'] print "dict['Mark3']: ", dict['Mark3'] print "dict['Total']: ", dict['Total'] print "dict['Average']: ", dict['Average']
```

if i give no of students as 2, I'm getting dict for 2nd database only and not for 1st one too.

output that i got

```
Please enter number of students:2
Enter the name of student: a
a
Enter the roll number of student:1
1
Enter the marks in subject 1:1
1
Enter the marks in subject 2:1
1
Enter the marks in subject 3:1
1
Total is:3
Average is :1
Enter the name of student:b
b
Enter the roll number of student:2
2
Enter the marks in subject 1:2
2
Enter the marks in subject 2:2
2
Enter the marks in subject 3:2
2
Total is:6
Average is :2
dict['Name']:b
dict['Rollno']:2
dict['Mark1']:2
dict['Mark2']:2
dict['Mark3']:2
dict['Total']:6
dict['Average']:2
```

Comment: for every `i`, you reset your definition of `dict` (which you shouldn't use as a name, as it means something in Python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code overwrites `dict` for every `i`. In addition, you shouldn't use the name `dict` as this causes confusion with the data type `dict` in Python.

One solution for you is to use a list of dictionaries, something like the following:

```
n = int(raw_input("Please enter number of students:"))

all_students = []

for i in range(0, n):
    stud_name = raw_input('Enter the name of student: ')
    print stud_name

    stud_rollno = input('Enter the roll number of student: ')
    print stud_rollno

    mark1 = input('Enter the marks in subject 1: ')
    print mark1

    mark2 = input('Enter the marks in subject 2: ')
    print mark2

    mark3 = input('Enter the marks in subject 3: ')
    print mark3

    total = (mark1 + mark2 + mark3)
    print"Total is: ", total

    average = total / 3
    print "Average is :", average

    all_students.append({
                            'Name': stud_name,
                            'Rollno': stud_rollno,
                            'Mark1': mark1,
                            'Mark2': mark2,
                            'Mark3': mark3,
                            'Total': total,
                            'Average': average
                            })

for student in all_students:
    print '\n'
    for key, value in student.items():
        print '{0}: {1}'.format(key, value)
```

By adding the responses for each new student onto the end of the list, we track all of them in turn. Finally, we print them out using the `keys` and `values` stored in the dictionary. This prints, with your inputs:

```
Name: a
Rollno: 1
Average: 1
Mark1: 1
Mark2: 1
Mark3: 1
Total: 3


Name: b
Rollno: 2
Average: 2
Mark1: 2
Mark2: 2
Mark3: 2
Total: 6
```

Comment: how to append them into a list??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this - this code makes a list of dictionaries.

Comment: i need to append them into a list like
name rollno mark1 mark2 mark3 total    average
# a           11           1            1              1          3 1
# b           22            2            2                 2         6 2

Comment: Can I ask why? This structure should be more useable than a basic list (or, in the case of what you're after, more likely a nested list)

Comment: Its my assignment to convert dict into list :p

Answer (score 1):

```
stud = {}
mrk = []
print("ENTER ZERO NUMBER FOR EXIT !!!!!!!!!!!!")
print("ENTER STUDENT INFORMATION ------------------------ ")
while True :
    rno = int(input("enter roll no.. :: -- "))
    if rno == 0 :
        break
    else:
         for i in range(3):
             print("enter marks  ",i+1," :: --  ",end = " ")
             n = int(input())
             mrk.append(n)
    stud[rno] = mrk
    mrk = []
print("Records are ------ ",stud)
print("\nRollNo\t Mark1\t Mark2\t Mark3\t Total")
tot = 0
for r in stud:
    print(r,"\t",end=" ")
    for m in stud[r]:
        tot = tot + m
        print(m,"\t",end=" ")
    print(tot)
    tot = 0
```